# Copying database to different hard disk

Tags: postgresql, migration, storage, copy, rails

Total noob at database administration here, excuse my ignorance.

I have a server running a Rails application that's using PostgreSQL. The database is saved on drive `/z/`, which seems to have filled up. I want to put a higher capacity drive and shift the database to that. How should I go about doing this? Should I copy the data folder from drive `/z/` to the new drive and then change the config files (could someone point me to what config changes I need to make?)

Or could I copy the data folder to the new hard disk, and then mount the disk as `/z/` and then I'll need no config changes?

Or is there some helper commands in postgres that provide a functionality to migrate between disks?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS. Output of `version()`:

> PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc
>   (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit

Comment: What operating system is this? How did you install PostgreSQL? What version, from where?

Comment: Hi! I should have included that information sorry, included now

Answer (score 4):

if you add a second disk i suggest to put data on to different tablespaces. a tablespace offers additional storage and is VERY easy to use:

```
mkdir /whatever
```

then in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE myspace LOCATION '/whatever';
ALTER DATABASE x SET TABLESPACE myspace;
```

of course you can also do this for single tables only.
and yes, alternatively you can move the entire data dir and tell the system where the new location is.